# open cover definition of compactness - technicality I don't understand

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $A$ be a subset of $X$.

$A$ is compact if out of every open cover $\{D_{j}\}_{j \in \mathcal{J}}$ of $A$, there exists a finite subcover (that is to say, there exist finitely many indices $\ j_{1},j_{2},.....j_{n}\in \mathcal{J}$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}D_{j_{k}}$).

$\ $

So let's say that I found an open cover $\{D_{j}\}_{j \in \mathcal{J}}$ for $A$, such that $\ A = \bigcup\limits_{j \in \mathcal{J}} D_{j}$.

$\ $

Is then true that there exist finitely many indices $\ j_{1},j_{2},.....j_{n}\in \mathcal{J}$ such that $\ A = \bigcup_{k=1}^{n}D_{j_{k}}$?

Comment: Provided that $A$ is compact, the answer is yes. That is exactly what the definition says. Or more precisely, the definition requires only $\subseteq$ and guarantees only $\subseteq$, but as you in fact found an open cover with $=$ and the finite subcover cannot be larger, you also get $=$

Comment: Thank you, it was the distinction between the case $\subseteq$ and $=$ which was confusing me.

Comment: Remember that if $X=Y$, then $X\subseteq Y$ (though not necessarily the other way around). $\subseteq$ means that they can be equal, and $\subsetneq$ means that they can't. ($\subset$ is ambiguous; some use it to mean they can't be equal, in analogy with $\le$ and $<$, but sometimes you'll see it mean that they can be equal.)

Comment: what do you mean by $\bigcup_{j \in J} D_{j_{k}}$ ? How do $j$ and $j_k$ relate?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It's fixed now.